# Moving inline code into function, with object name generation

Tags: javascript

I am customizing Denis Gritcyuk's [Popup date picker](http://javascriptkit.com/script/script2/timestamp.shtml).

1. This pop-up script uses inline Javascript in a `href` link, to set the selected date into the `input` field, in the parent window, that is was called for. An example URL looks like:

   ```
   <a href="javascript:window.opener.document.formname.field.value='03-10-2011';
            window.close();">3</a>
   ```
2. The input field name, (e.g. `document.formname.field`), is passed to the script as a string parameter.

I would like to add things done when that link is clicked (e.g. change background color of field, set flag, etc.). So while this DOES work, it's getting **ugly** fast.

```
<a href="javascript:window.opener.document.formname.field.value='03-10-2011';
         window.opener.document.formname.field.style.backgroundColor='#FFB6C1'; 
         window.close();">3</a>
```

How would I move these inline commands into a JS function? This would give me much cleaner URLs and code. The URL would now look something like

```
<a href="javascript:updateField ('document.formname.field', '03-10-2011');">3</a>
```

with a function like (this example obviously does NOT work):

```
function updateField (str_target, str_datetime) {
    var fieldName = "window.opener" + str_target;
    [fieldName].value = str_datetime;
    [fieldName].style.backgroundColor = '#FFB6C1';
    // Set flag, etc.
    window.close();
}
```

So any suggestions on how this can be done, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd prefer to hide the dom path tracing back from the current window back to the opener. It's appropriate to bake that into the function since the function will always be used in the context of that child popup. Then your function call is cleaner and more readable. Obviously, replace "myField" with the ID of the field you're intending to update.

```
<a href="javascript:window.opener.updateField( '03-10-2011', 'myField' );">3</a>

function updateField ( str_date, str_fieldname ) {

    var fieldToUpdate = document.getElementById( str_fieldname );

    fieldToUpdate.value = str_date;
    fieldToUpdate.style.backgroundColor = '#FFB6C1';

    // Set flag, etc.
    window.close();

}
```

Comment: I find your solution very readable and elegant. Only problem is that I can't get it to work. When I press the link, NOTHING happens. I'm pretty sure the function is NOT being called, because I put an alert in there.
    <a href="javascript:updateField ('RapNet_expires', '03-10-2011');">3</a>

Comment: @ShmuelA.Kam: Use console.log instead of alert. Its much more user-friendly.

Comment: Works now, with minor changes. Most appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I have to confess not having tested the code, or I would have caught the need to deal with which window context the function was running in.

Answer (score 1):

You're acessing the property incorrectly. Try:

```
function updateField (str_target, str_datetime) {
    var fieldName = window.opener;
    str_target = str_target.split('.');
    for (var i = 0; i < str_target.length; i++)
        fieldName = fieldName[str_target[i]];
    fieldName.value = str_datetime;
    fieldName.style.backgroundColor = '#FFB6C1';
    // Set flag, etc.
    window.close();
}
```

The bracket notation (`[]`) is only used for properties of objects, not objects themselves. If you found my post helpful, please vote for it.

Comment: I needed Jonas' answer to understand what that loop was doing. That method looks a bit awkward, no?

Comment: True. I didn't elaborate my answer. Jonas provided the explanation and I provided the code. Makes it complete right? Oh, and what method is it that looks awkward to you?

Comment: I thought that splitting the string and iterating through it was awkward, inefficient. But yes, Paul's method does "break" the API. Luckily it was a VERY small change. I'm very happy with the results.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a string and evaluate it as code using the `eval` function, but I would recommend against it.

There are a couple of things wrong with your code:

1. You cannot use the [] operator in a global context, you have to suffix it on an object, so you can say `window["opener"]` and this will be equivalent to `window.opener`, but there is no such thing as simply `["window"]`
2. When navigating nested properties, as in `window.opener.document` you cannot navigate multiple levels using the [] operator. I.e. `window["opener.document"]` is not allowed. You must use `window["opener"]["document"]` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on using [] Do you see any preference in either of the two ways Aadith and Paul suggested to access the fieldname?

Comment: Paul's method is better. It's faster and more elegant. However, my method works out of the box - you need not change any code other than the `updateField` function. It does not break the interface. =)